# About concrete finit Galois extension.

Tags: galois-theory

I'm trying to solve this problem, but I don't know what I can do.

Let $f(x)=x^3+2x+1$ over $\mathbb{F_5}$. Let $E$ the decomposition field of $f$ over $\mathbb{F_5}$ and $\alpha$ a root of $f$ in this field. Proof that $E=\mathbb{F_5}(\alpha)$.

I try to calculate $E$ and show that one root generates the other two, but I can't finalize this way.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your polynomial is irreducible, and the fields are finite, so try Frobenius! $\alpha^5$ is another root :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: $\mathbb{F}_5(\alpha)/\mathbb{F}_5$ is normal, since these are finite fields.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to the abstract approach, you can explicitly calculate the roots of $x^3+2x+1$ in terms of $\alpha$.  For example, you could use long division and the quadratic formula, or try to solve for the coefficients of a general element of $\mathbb{F}_5[\alpha]$.  This is a nice exercise.

Comment: This is the brute force approach. As already mentioned by Jyrki, Frobenius is our friend! [Even for the explicit calculation of the roots]

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all answers.
I have shown that $\mathbb{F_5(\alpha)}$ is the field with $5^3$ elements (easy to proof). Then, is generated by $x^{5^3}-x$ and for this reason $\alpha$ is root of this polynomial. This works for every $\alpha$ root of $f$. Then $f(x) | x^{5^3}-x$ and this proof that $f$ have all roots in $\mathbb{F_f(\alpha)}$.

But with this trick is easier.
"Hint: F5(α)/F5 is normal, since these are finite field".
Then every polynomial with root in $\mathbb{F_5(\alpha)}$